# Deserialize field with array or string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

in my .NET 5 application I deserialize data using the System.Text.Json functions. This works for the most part.
Except for one field in the received JSON document, which can contain a number array, a string array or a single string (without array).

I can handle the first two cases by defining the field in my target type as `List<dynamic>`. But if the third case occurs, the standalone string, an exception is thrown.

How can I achieve that this third case is also handled without exception. I would prefer to get a single element in my list. Is this possible?

This are 3 possible values in JSON:

```
{
  "range": [
    0,
    100
  ]
}

{
  "range": [
    "yes",
    "no"
  ]
}

{
  "range": "n/a"
}
```

Comment: You could deserialize this to a `Dictionary<string, object>` then check the types.  Json is really just a dictionary anyways.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, too. This comes close to Guru Strons dynamic deserialization idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this custom converter

```
var testRange = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestRange>(json);

public class TestRange
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(ToListJsonConverter))]
    public List<object>? range { get; set; }
}

public class ToListJsonConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<List<object>>
{
    public override List<object> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            var arr = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(ref reader, options);
            if (arr is null) return default;
                  else  return  arr;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String) return new List<object> { reader.GetString() };
        return default;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<object> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need either to write custom converter or dive into dynamic deserialization for example with `JsonDocument`:

```cs
// .NET 7 feature here - raw string literals:
var jsons = new[]
{
    """
    {
      "range": [
        0,
        100
      ]
    }
    """,
    """
    {
      "range": [
        "yes",
        "no"
      ]
    }
    """,
    """
    {
      "range": "n/a"
    }
    """
};

foreach (var jsonStr in jsons)
{
    using var jd = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonStr);
    var jsonElement = jd.RootElement.GetProperty("range");
    switch (jsonElement.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Array:
            var array = jsonElement.Deserialize<object[]>();
            Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
            break;
        case JsonValueKind.String:
            Console.WriteLine(jsonElement.GetString());
            break;
    }
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have chosen the converter solution based on the answer of Serge. But your dynamic deserialization example is also interesting and will help me to get a deeper understanding of the system.text.json classes.

Comment: @ringhat was glad to help! Feel free to accept and upvote any answer =)