# Jsonconverter but the field is either empty object or string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, mapping

I'm having issue that the response from a 3rd party site has some fields that can be either empty object or a string like below

```json
[
{
  "name" : "XXX", 
  "contact" : {}
},
{
  "name" : "YYY",
  "contact" : "123456"
}
]
```

And I need to mapping those objects into my custom class.

```cs
public List<SuccessFactor> ReadAndDeserialIntoObject(string filePath)
        {
            var objSer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomClass>>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
            Console.WriteLine(objSer);

            return objSer;
        }
```

but since the contact field are "{}" and  "123456" so the code above could not work.
I'm not sure how can I declare the successfactor class to match with the API response

```cs
 class CustomClass
{
   public string name; 
   public Contact contact; 
}

or

class CustomClass
{ 
  public string name; 
  public string contact;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize field with array or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853111/deserialize-field-with-array-or-string)

Comment: Would replacing all instance of "{}" with "" in the string before deserialization work?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach would be to use the `JToken` type:

```cs
class CustomClass
{
    public string name; 
    public JToken Contact; 
}
```

And then analyze it:

```
foreach (var customClass in col)
{

    if (customClass.Contact is JObject jo) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jo.ToObject<Contact>());
    }
    else if(customClass.Contact is JValue val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Also you can implement [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm). Something to start with:

```
class CustomClass
{
    public string name;
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(ContactOrStringConv))]
    public Contact Contact; 
}

class Contact
{
    public string? SomeProp { get; set; }
}

class ContactOrStringConv : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter<Contact>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Contact? value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override Contact? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Contact? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue,
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonToken.String => new Contact
            {
                SomeProp = (string?)reader.Value
            },
            JsonToken.StartObject => serializer.Deserialize<Contact>(reader),
            _ => default
        };
}
```